# C output of hexadecimal division different from all other sources

Tags: c, hex, division, integer-division

I want to divide two hex numbers:

for example: `88555680/10000`

Now, from online hex calculators, I find:

[8855 as result here](https://www.calculator.net/hex-calculator.html?number1=88555680&c2op=%2F&number2=10000&calctype=op&x=33&y=22)

[8855.568 as result here](https://www.miniwebtool.com/hex-calculator/?number1=88555680&operate=4&number2=10000)

And in python I find:

```
>>> hex(int("0x88555680",16)//int("0x10000", 16))
'0x8855'
```

Here is my C code:

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()  {
    int a = 0x88555680;
    int b = 0x10000;
    int c = a/b;
    printf("a%x, b%x, c%x\n", a, b, c);
}
```

With output:

```
a88555680, b10000, cffff8856
```

In C, I find **8856**, while with Python, and online calculators, I find **8855**

**Question:** Why is the C output not 8855? Why is it 8856? Should it not be 8855.something and then truncated towards 0, thus 8855?

I'm very new to C, it might be an obvious error.

Comment: Because `0x88555680` is not fitting into *signed* `int`. Check this one: https://ideone.com/vGJo1G

Comment: The first chapters of a beginner-level C programming book should mention the numerical limits of `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On common systems `int` is a 32-bit type whose max value is `0x7FFFFFFF`. Your value of `0x88555680` is out of range for `int`. The compiler should warn you about this; if you don't see a warning then I recommend adjusting compiler settings.

Also your code causes undefined behaviour by using `%x` to print an `int`. The `%x` specifier may only be used for `unsigned int`.

To fix your code in this case use `unsigned int` instead of `int` for all 3 variables.  If you want to deal with larger numbers you can use `unsigned long long`, or `uint64_t`. (In those cases you will need to update the printf format specifiers too).